# Stackoverflow error when saving an Object's toString value - Java/Hibernate/Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have the following sample entities:

**Institution**

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(InstitutionAuditListener.class)
public class Institution extends Auditable<String> {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<RegisteredProgram> registeredPrograms;

    private String name;
}
```

**RegisteredProgram**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EntityListeners(RegisteredProgramAuditListener.class)
public class RegisteredProgram extends Auditable<String> {

   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id", nullable = false)
   @JsonBackReference
   private Institution institution;

   @Embedded
   private RegistrationRequirement registrationRequirement;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "registeredProgram", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JsonManagedReference
   private List<Official> officialList;
}
```

**Official**

```
@Data
@Entity
@EntityListeners(OfficialAuditListener.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Official extends Auditable<String> {

    private String name;
    private String position;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "REGISTERED_PROGRAM_ID", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private RegisteredProgram registeredProgram;
}
```

**Audit Log**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuditLog extends AuditBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private Long entityId;

    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private Boolean isDeleted = false;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    @Convert(converter = JpaConverterJson.class)
    private String jsonObject;
}
```

When I attempted to save an instance of **Official**'s object *toString()* value into **AuditLog**'s ***jsonObject*** field, I encountered the error below:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:538) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at com.tesda8.region8.program.registration.model.entities.RegisteredProgram.toString(RegisteredProgram.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:473) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at com.tesda8.region8.program.registration.model.entities.Institution.toString(Institution.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at com.tesda8.region8.program.registration.model.entities.RegisteredProgram.toString(RegisteredProgram.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
```

I was wondering if there are any annotations in spring/hibernate that could prevent this issue to occur or is there any other way that i could save the object's (JSON) value to an object's column in spring? I was assuming that `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` should've prevented this issue to happen.

**UPDATE**

1. I already tried to used ***toString()*** method for objects through Lombok's `@Data` annotation
2. I also tried to use `String.valueOf(official)`

Comment: Clearly it's the recursive reference (`RegisteredProgram->List<Official> ... Official->RegisteredProgram`).  Is `@JsonBackReference` supposed to break this loop?  If so it may not be working.

Comment: Yes, `@JsonBackReference` should have broken the loop. But apparently, when i tried to set the field by: `auditLog.setJsonObject(official.toString());` then saved the entity, that's when the error occurred. I'm still trying to figure out a workaround to make this work.

Comment: Does Auditable override toString?

Comment: @tgdavies no it does not. all of the parent classes does not override the toString method

Comment: Don't use `@Data` with entities, or at least not to generate `equals`, `hashCode` **and** `toString`. It will lead to issues with bi-directional relations, leading to an unlimited number of calls to `toString` back-and-forth. Provide a proper implementation that doesn't do this. More info https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheers for M. Deinum's insights regarding my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65388643/14806310

The root cause of my problem was indeed using `toString()` by Lombok's `@Data` to save the details of my entity to a field, which was problematic right off the bat. I did try to override the `toString()` method of `RegisteredProgram`, which then solved the StackOverflow error, but still my approach on saving the JSON object was weird.

So rather than saving the object to `String` json column through `toString()`, I created a new HashMap field `entityAttributes` for my entity to persist a JSON object.

**UPDATED AuditLog Entity**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuditLog extends AuditBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private Long entityId;

    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private Boolean isDeleted = false;

    @Convert(converter = HashMapConverter.class)
    private Map<String, Object> entityAttributes;
}
```

More details on how to save the JSON object can be seen through this link:
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persist-json-object

Also, moving forward, it really is recommended to create your own `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` method for your entities and **don't** rely on Lombok etc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the fact you are using Lombok's `@Data` annotation to generate the `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` method. This will lead to several issues/oddities (more info in [this blog post I wrote](https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/)).

Trying to use a Jackson `@JsonBackReference` will ofcourse not solve the generating of the `toString` method, this will only help with creating JSON using the Jackson library.

What happens is that your `toString` of `Institution` will call the `toString` of the `RegisteredProgram`. Which will call the `toString` of `Institution` again, which will call the `toString` of `RegisteredProgram` again which.... (well you probably get the drift).

Don't rely on the `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods from the `@Data` functionality to Lombok as, as mentioned in the start, it will lead to issues. Instead write your own `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` or at least declare what needs to be part of those methods (the end result might even be that it is easier to write those methods by hand).

On the other hand, isn't storing the `toString` value a bit weird in the first place?

### Related Links

1. https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/
2. https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/

Comment: thank you for your insights mate! moving forward I will be creating my own `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods for my entities rather than depending on Lombok.